# Why isn't Modus Ponens valid here

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have the following:

$(\neg A \lor B) \rightarrow (\neg A \lor B) \\ (\neg A \lor B) \\ \vdash \neg A \lor B $

And in my mind this seems like a legitimate use of the Modus Ponens rule. But the textbook I'm using disagrees.

Why is this wrong?

Edit:

The textbook has the following line in it as a part of a larger exercise:

[image]

The exercise asks to state whether the use of a giving rule is valid in each case. In the answer section it is marked as an invalid use.

Comment: Why do you say the textbook disagrees?

Comment: That's fine. Please post the context in which your textbook disagrees more precisely.

Comment: The shot you posted agrees with what you typed before the edit. I repeat: why do you say the textbook disagrees?

Comment: @GitGud the textbook JUST disagrees with the statement, that you can use MP for this example. It does not elaborate as to why. Sorry if I didn't make that more apparent.

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: Don't know myself, it's a digitized photocopy of a photocopy with many pages missing.

Comment: While the use of Modus Ponens here is technically logically valid, it is also an example of the fallacy of Circular Reasoning -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $$(\lnot A \lor B) \rightarrow (\lnot A \lor B) \equiv \lnot(\lnot A \lor B) \lor (\lnot A \lor B) \equiv \top$$ In other words, the first premise is a tautology. It says nothing more than "either $\lnot(\lnot A \lor B)$ or else $(\lnot A \lor B)$ holds.  And in assuming the law of the excluded middle, one of the two disjuncts must be true, and thus the entire  statement is tautologically true.

The second premise is $\lnot A \lor B$.

The argument then can be stated as follows:

$\quad \top\tag{premise 1} $
$\quad \lnot A \lor B\tag{premise 2}$
$\therefore \lnot A \lor B\tag{repetition of premise 2}$

So the conclusion becomes a reiteration of the second premise.

Perhaps that is what your book was attempting to convey?

Comment: I see what you mean, but the use is still valid, even if it is redundant in this case, right?

Comment: Well, trivially so, perhaps. But it is like no different than the argument: $$p\rightarrow p$$ $$p$$ $$\therefore p$$

Comment: Gotcha, well this settles it then. Thanks!

Comment: Inferring $p$ from $p \rightarrow p$ and $p$ is a perfectly good application of *modus ponens* in all the presentations of first-order logic that I have ever seen. To say it is illegitimate or invalid seems bizarre.

Comment: @Rob I never said it was invalid to do so.

Comment: @amWhy: I agree that you didn't say that, but the OP accepted what you said as settling the issues with his or her textbook.

Answer (score 4):

To infer $p$ from $p \rightarrow p$ and $p$ *is* a legitimate application of modus ponens. It isn't a particularly useful inference, but it is a correct one.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be wrong. If $C=C'=\neg A\vee B$, then a correct use of modus ponens is simply $(C'\to C)\wedge C'$ gives $C$, which is what you have.

Comment: What you're doing, essentially, is proving that $((C'\to C)\wedge C')\to C$ is a tautology.

Comment: $C, C'$ cannot both be equivalent to $\lnot A \lor B$.  Settle on your assignment.  In any case $((\lnot C \to C) \land \lnot C) = ((C\lor C) \land \lnot C)\equiv C\land \lnot C\equiv \bot$, But of course, anything and everything follows from a contradiction.  But how instructive is this post, posted more than a year after the question was posted?

Comment: @amWhy Why not? I'm using both $C$ and $C'$ to better illustrate modus ponens. Forgive me if I'm wrong in that. 

I didn't notice the time of postage: I must have had active rather than new questions displayed.

Comment: That's fine...I was just confused, because the original question was of the form $C \lor \

Comment: oops, I clicked on the add comment button when I hadn't finished with it.  Actually, it would be correct if you had said $((C\to C) \land C )\to  C$, in your first comment above, (that is, setting $C:= \lnot A \lor B$.  That is equivalent to saying $$(\lnot C \lor C)\land C \equiv C$$

Comment: @amWhy Well, I had to stay consistent. It's still correct.

Comment: $$((C'\to C)\land C') \equiv (C\lor C)\land C' \equiv (C \land C') \equiv \bot$$ That anything follows from a contradiction (including C), does not modus ponens make.

Comment: Any way, I did not intend to come here to argue with you.  You're free to stand by your answer.  Good day!

Comment: I don't understand: $C'$ is not $\lnot C$.

Comment: Well, Good luck!